# Selective touch screen input in linux (wacom - or X11?)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, input, touch, x11

I was wondering what would be the most straightforward way to have a selective touch screen input with wacom devices. I have an x1 yoga (laptop/tablet with the latest gen wacom touch and pen input. When I use the tablet for writing with a pen, I would like to be able to use touch to scroll, but in order to avoid palm rejection issues, I would hope to only have a small area of a screen (say a rectangle on the left side), that is responsive to touch input). Touching any other area of the screen would have no effect, and be disregarded.

I run ubuntu 16.04.

What would the best way to achieve this be? Wacom driver? X11? window manager? other?

It seems like this is not currently supported by the wacom linux drivers unfortunately. I would imagine I could update it basically to ignore certain input, but it'd take me some time to get familiarized with the code base (any pointers here would be greatly appreciated!). Is this the best way to do this?

Or, would this maybe be possible with just using X11 libs? I can see it's straightforward to log input from mouse/touch-screen devices, but could one write a small program that causes X to simply ignore touch input if it's beyond some range?

thanks

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question *may* be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se]. Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Comment: thanks for your comment - I meant it as a programming question, but perhaps  a "high level" one. I'll get it moved.